# Customizing bootstrap4-beta scss in Angular-CLI project not reflecting the change

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change the context primary to some color other than blue(default).

## Technology stack

- Angular-CLI project with angular4
- Bootstrap@4.0.0-beta

## Steps I followed

- 1.executed command in ng-cli "ng set defaults.styleExt scss"
- 2.In angular-cli.json changed styles to be an array with two paths:
- 3.Created src/styles/vendor.scss. Navigate to node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss and copy the contents of that file to  vendor.scss.
- 4.Add src/styles/_variables.scss and add it as an import at the top of vendor.scss
  changed all the paths to point to node_modules.
- 5.then added the override in _src/styles/_variables.scss

## angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
  "styles/vendor.scss",
  "styles/main.scss"
]
```

## vendor.scss

```
@import "variables";

@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
```

## src/styles/_variables.scss

```
$theme-colors: (
  primary: cyan)
```

But all in vain ...nothing getting changed.
Please let me know if any one has started witth Bootstrap4-beta
Thanks In advance